# Monitor SOAP messages and save it into a file

Tags: apache-axis

I am working on Apache Tomcat 6 and Axis2 for web services.

I want to monitor SOAP messages which are exchanged with client and server and save the data into a file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Storm](http://storm.codeplex.com/) is a test client for SOAP services.

To capture the traffic between your client and the server, you could use a proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: dear i am developing the soap monitor and need help if any API is available using which can store all those SOAP exchanges with Client and Server.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in modules samples (in samples/userguide) describing this case.

Personally I found simpler just to add a logging code in my generated <...MessageReceiverInOut> class. Just dumping out input/output envelopes for my particular service.